# x-ray gem in Rails with IDE Sublime

Tags: sublimetext3

I got error opening the file from browser after ctrl + shift + x
I can't find the correct location of installed Sublime text 3 in my Ubuntu 14.04.

```
ls /usr/local/bin/subl
ls: cannot access /usr/local/bin/subl: No such file or directory
```

I tried to make a configuration file **.xrayconfig**

```
:editor: '/usr/local/bin/subl'
```

but the problem, is that I dont know the correct location of the installed Sublime Text 3 in my ubuntu.

I got error in browser console like:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/_xray/open?path=/home/guest/lets_debug/app/views/posts/index.html.erb
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the command line and enter

```
which subl
```

If there is an executable file name `subl` anywhere in your `$PATH` it will be printed. I'm guessing it'll show up in `/usr/bin`, depending on how you installed Sublime.

*Hint*: if you are searching for a file in your `$PATH` that may be in there several times, use `which -a filename` to print *all* locations.

Answer (score 0):

> By default, Xray will open files with Sublime Text, looking for /usr/local/bin/subl.

https://github.com/brentd/xray-rails#configuration

Find where your sublime is installed

```
which subl
```

If the path is different than what is expected creating a symlink will solve this problem.

In my case it was installed at `/usr/bin/subl`

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```